# Using jQuery to set active class in PHP

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

First, why do I always get downvoted when I ask about this question? Here's the question.

I got tag PHP in `a href`.

Here's my code:

```
<nav class="main-navi">
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="?r=site/index" >
            Home
            <span class="dot"></span>
            <span class="corner"></span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="?r=site/fotoportfolio">
            Portfolio
            <span class="dot"></span>
            <span class="corner"></span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="?r=site/fotoabout">
            About
            <span class="dot"></span>
            <span class="corner"></span>
        </a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="?r=site/fotoservice">
            services
            <span class="dot"></span>
            <span class="corner"></span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="?r=site/fotoblog">
            Blog
            <span class="dot"></span>
            <span class="corner"></span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="?r=site/fotocontact">
            contacts
            <span class="dot"></span>
            <span class="corner"></span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
<em id="showHideMenu" class="show-hide-menu fa fa-bars" href="#"></em></nav>
```

And I include 2 scripts:

```
<script>
    var loc = window.location.href;
    $('.main-navi ul li a').each(function () {
        var status = loc.indexOf($(this).attr('href')) > -1;
        $(this).toggleClass('active', status);
    });
</script>
<script>
    console.log(location.href);
</script>
```

The first script function is to give an `active` class when I load the page, and the second script just to know the link location.

In second script, I have output in console like this:

```
?r=site/index
```

And the url is:

```
localhost/blablabla/frontend/web/?r=site/index
```

The problem is: I don't have the class `active` in the navbar whenever I load the page.

Example: If I load index, 'home' doesn't get class `active`. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: is this script tag in `<head>`? If so the elements don't exist yet...wrap in `$(function(){ /* code */})`. Or move this below the html it refers to

Comment: Also please note any errors in browser console

Comment: i put the script before close body tag sir </body>. sorry, do you min i should do this  $(document).ready(function () {  var loc = window.location.href;
    $('.main-navi ul li a').each(function () {
        var status = loc.indexOf($(this).attr('href')) > -1;
        $(this).toggleClass('active', status);
    }); });

Comment: Are you absolutely sure class isn't being set in the live html? Have you inspected it in browser dev tools element inspector?

Comment: i already check in inspect element but no eror in console sir. before i put tag PHP it work great. but as soon as i put tag PHP in href the script is not working but no error in console

Comment: try this ... `alert($('.main-navi ul li a').length)` ..should be at least the 5 or 6 shown in that count

Comment: @ charlietfl the page says 6 sir, may i ask u what 6 means sir

Answer (score 0):

The toogleClass() is not working as expected for you. Change it to:

```
if (status) {
    $(this).addClass('active');
}
```

https://jsbin.com/beyinaxoka/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: sir, if i change var loc like you do. do i have to create 6 var? because in your code in var loc you change it to ?r=site/index

Comment: No, not at all. I merely changed the value to prove the concept. In a real world scenario, you would have it set to what you have it above.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the bug.  I only needed to add `$(document).ready(function () { });` and it worked like a charm.

Comment: Congo! :D Earn Scholar badge :)